# How to retrieve id of newly added row in JModelAdmin?

Tags: component

I am modifying a component. In its model file, it creates a class that extends JModelAdmin. In its save() function, it takes form data, then calls parent:save(). I am trying to get the id of the newly added row.

I am new to joomla, but I know the $this variable should contain relevant info. $this->id does not return the newly created id, but rather, 0. I think this makes sense since $this would not know about the id created in the parent save function.

So what do I do to get the id from the parent save?

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 7):

It is saved in the model state. You can retrieve it with:

```
$this->getState($this->getName() . '.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Figured it out after some more research.

$this->getState($this->getName().'.id')

Man, there are some convoluted posts out there about how to do this! Glad I found something this elegant!

Comment: Please remove this identical answer because @Anibal answered it one minute sooner than you :)